# Are there some natural instances of thermosensitizer?

Tags: evolution, molecular-genetics, behaviour, thermoregulation

Let's define thermosensitizer as any chemical or biological agent that can sensitize the cells to heat. In lab setting, thermosensitization seems to be achievable, such as by inhibiting chaperone activity.

I wonder if in nature there are some instances of thermosensitizer? Specifically, the question is not concerning the various regulatory mechanisms of the cells to survive heat. It's more about if some organism can exert/secrete chemicals on another organism to make the latter more sensitive to heat, for example in self-defense or for killing.

Answer (score 4):

Geldanamycin/radicicol would be examples. They are both Hsp90 (protein chaperone) inhibitors. There is [a lot of literature on their biological effects](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3260023/) (see references therein), specifically their role modulating genetic interactions and also as [chemotherapeutic agents for killing cancer cells](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25403416/).

Both of these natural compounds [are created by microbes as antibiotic chemicals for interaction with other organisms](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3603443/).